# Can I use functions to determine the min and max of a date data type

Tags: javascript, html, input

Is it possible to get max="" in the input to be 5 days after value no matter which day it is, using a function in js?

Enter your shipping date

Comment: A function by definition can be made to do anything that JavaScript can do. Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: Please read the [tour] _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
date.valueAsDate = new Date(); // set date to today

const maximum = new Date();
maximum.setDate(maximum.getDate() + 5); // add five days to todays date
date.max = maximum.toISOString().split("T")[0]; // set maximum attribute of date
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date">
```

Comment: how would I change the code if I would want to create a minimum and a maximum

Comment: `date.min=...`?